# How to assign the time for the remote vpn client to get access to vpn server?

Tags: windows-xp

How can i allocate the specific time to the remote VPN client so that after the allocated time the VPN client get automatically disconnected for the VPN server?

Comment: What client are you using? The one built into Windows or a third party one? The built-in one has a option to disconnect after the connection has been idle for a while.

Comment: Could you clarify?  Do you want the VPN client to connect for a specific amount of time then disconnect or time out after a certain of inactivity?

Comment: I am having the VPN server in my lab. And one of the client is located in US. He is using cisco VPN client to connect to the server. Now, I want to define the time period to him to access the Server.So, that after some time he is automatically disconnected from the Server and couldnot access the VPN server.